# SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD not recognised after Sonoma update

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility, ssd, sonoma

After updating MacBookPro (Silicon M1Pro) I cannot get it to recognise my external SSD Drive at all. Used as Time Machine drive.

Not seen in Disk Utility, Finder, Terminal (diskutil list external) or the SanDisk Utility.  Same on another MacOS Sonoma machine. Drive is password protected. No prompt to enter p/w.

Have restarted multiple times with SSD connected and not.
Cable is OK as used on other devices.
SSD is drawing power when connected (0.3W).
Is this a SanDisk  issue or a Sonoma one?

Comment: Maybe reinstall SanDisk Security Software for the SSD?

Comment: It would help to get the results of ‘diskutil list’ (execute that command in Terminal) with the drive connected. Paste the results into your original question. Something may have happened to the drive and that might help us figure it out

Comment: Is the password protection on the drive due to a macOS feature, or due to some kind of SanDisk software?

Comment: Have updated SanDisk Security to latest version. Same issue. When the SSD is connected, it shows the right icon (Extreme 1TB) but still has the text "Attach a supported SanDisk drive".

Comment: DiskUtil list does not show the external SSD at all, just the internal and virtual ones.    
donsteele@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
 
/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk3

Comment: The SanDisk Security is a WD software feature, not part of MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same issue and made this account just to reply here. The firmware update is not needed for my device according to the website in the other answer. The password protection is a SanDisk feature and after all my digging my best guess is that the SanDisk software has not been updated to support Sonoma yet. The password feature effectively blocks the MacBook from reading anything about the SSD and that feature isn't working properly. I opened a ticket with SanDisk last week but no reply yet.

Answer (score 0):

How old is the SSD?
Western Digital has published a firmware update for their SSDs, have a look at [Your Portable SSD May Require a Firmware Update](https://support-en.wd.com/app/firmwareupdate).
Links are provided for macOS and Windows.

From the manufacturer:

> a firmware issue that can cause SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD V2, SanDisk Extreme Pro Portable SSD V2, and WD My Passport SSD products to unexpectedly disconnect from a computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I use Paragon software for NTFS. Upgrading Paragon from 15.9 to 15.11 fixed the issue.